# How can I display my GameCube on my PC?

Tags: pc, technical-issues, nintendo-gamecube

I am thinking about getting a GameCube or a Wii, since it can play GameCube Games too.

I do not have any sort of TV nor did I plan on getting one, I only have a PC with a 16:10 ViewSonic Monitor (which does support 16:9 ratios but with black bars).

Optimum would be a solution where I can just hook up the GameCube to my PC entirely, including sound and displaying the video in some sort of software. What is the best solution for that?

I have found [this](http://www.amazon.de/CSL-Software-Videoadapter-Bearbeitung-Nachbearbeitung-vergoldete/dp/B00EOMIDXG/), but I do not know how the software actually looks like, so I cannot tell if works or not. Do not mention emulators please, since the games I want most [cannot](https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=Star_Wars_Rogue_Squadron_II:_Rogue_Leader) be [emulated](https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=Star_Wars_Rogue_Squadron_III:_Rebel_Strike).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That cord you linked to looks like the exact device I would search for if I wanted to do this. If any direct connection from GC to PC is possible it would be an adapter just like that one. I suspect it will simply be plug and play, or download drivers on its own.

[This site](http://isitaboutmygamecube.blogspot.com/2010/11/gamecube-audiovisual-choices.html)
advises an adapter just like the one you linked, but offers a couple other options.

That site claims the proprietary (japan release only) Gamecube Component Cable is the best, but you will probably have a hard time finding it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer so far. Lot of trash around that topic on the internet. The question that remains is, if such a cable as I linked has any decent software suitable for gaming. I do not mind to play in a window, but it should be without much delay. Is there any known 3rd Party Software out there that can be used for just displaying it? I don't know how such a device identifies.

Comment: @leetfan The term for such devices and software is "video capture".

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I know that term. Still does not explain how the device identifies and what software could be used to display the output etc. Those devices are probably not made for gaming and every extensive lag will have undesired side effects, especially when playing the aforementioned games.

Comment: @leetfan Perhaps some research is in order then. The device "identifies" as a video capture device. They all pretty much work the same from the point of view of the computer.

Comment: @leetfan You don't need 3rd party software usually. Its just plug and play. Most computers have a default way of handling video/audio coming from USB. I don't think anyone understands why you expect it to require a 3rd party program

Comment: Well, if you don't understand it, why do you say it is irrelevant then? As I said before, I am worried about display lag.

Comment: @leetfan Just buy the cord. There is no reason to be unduly worried about display lag.